# How do I normalize my current database structure

Tags: mysql, normalization

I got headache to get a correct result when using `FIND_IN_SET` or `LIKE`.

Example my value in database like this `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`.

Lets say I have one form with many checkboxes. Each checkbox is coming with dynamic value which can add by users. Example value is colors and have `green, yellow, white, black, red, pink, brown, etc...`

My current structure `tbl_colors` & `tbl_users`

```
color_id  color_name
----------------------
1         yellow
2         black
3         green
.         ...
.         ...
20        pink
```

tbl_users

```
user_id  color_id
----------------------
1         1,2,3,4
2         3,4,5,6,8,9,10
3         1
.         ...
.         ...
20        1,10,20
```

**Question**

How do I normalize & restructure my current database above and easy me to count how much users like yellow color, brown color etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need an extra link table.

```
tbl_colors
----------
color_id
color_name 

tbl_users
---------
user_id
...

tbl_users_colors_link
---------------------
user_id
color_id
```

Please note that link table shouldn't include unique fields. Also no primary key is required. Only indexing id fields make sense.

Comment: The link table should have a primary key - an innodb clustered one.

Comment: MRA hasn't mentioned the db engine but my answer applies to InnoDB as well, since InnoDB automatically creates a 6 bytes unqiue key internally. You don't need to create one.

Answer (score 1):

Put USER in his/her own table, then record their preferences in USER_COLOUR, e.g.

```
User ID    Colour ID
1          10
1          11
1          15
2          10
2          7
```

Note the repeat occurrences of user ID and Colour ID.  This is known as a **many to many** relationship, because 1 user can like many colours, and each colour can be liked by many users.

Answer (score 1):

```
table colors
id
color_id
color_name

table users
id

table user_color( or whatever )
id
user_id
color_id
```

This way you have a separate table and one entry per user chosen color instead of multiple numbers per color_id row.
Then you can just count the number of rows returned based on the the color_id in the query.
Thats how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

[many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

```
tbl_user_color
id, user_id,    color_id
--------------------
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   1   4
5   3   1
6   20  1
7   20  10
8   20  20
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following links:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Then design your schema something along the lines of (omitted referential integrity):

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists colours;
create table colours
(
colour_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) unique not null,
user_counter int unsigned not null default 0
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists user_colours;
create table user_colours
(
user_id int unsigned not null,
colour_id smallint unsigned not null,
primary key (user_id, colour_id) -- note the clustered composite primary key
)
engine=innodb;

delimiter #

create trigger user_colours_after_ins_trig after insert on user_colours
for each row
begin
 update colours set user_counter = user_counter + 1 where colour_id = new.colour_id;
end#

delimiter ;


insert into users (username) values ('alpha'),('beta'),('delta'),('gamma');

insert into colours (name) values ('red'),('green'),('blue');

insert into user_colours (user_id, colour_id) values
(1,1),(1,3),
(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),
(4,3);

select * from users;
+---------+----------+
| user_id | username |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | alpha    |
|       2 | beta     |
|       3 | delta    |
|       4 | gamma    |
+---------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from colours;
+-----------+-------+--------------+
| colour_id | name  | user_counter |
+-----------+-------+--------------+
|         1 | red   |            2 |
|         2 | green |            1 |
|         3 | blue  |            3 |
+-----------+-------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from user_colours;    
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | colour_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         1 |
|       1 |         3 |
|       2 |         1 |
|       2 |         2 |
|       2 |         3 |
|       4 |         3 |
+---------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```